# Meizu MX4 gps possibly not working

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gps, meizu-mx4

I just received my mx4. I played around with the phone yesterday and tested various stuff including the maps paps.
They either told me, that detecting my location was impossible or the accuracy was very low. Anyway, the nearby scope works but it probably uses wifi to locate me.
I installed the sensors app from the store and it shows gps coordinates but an accuracy of more than 5k meters.
So what is that a knownissue? Is it my phone? Is there a way to fix this? May I have been too impatient for a gps fix?

Comment: I have also fidgeted with the GPS, i'm not sure if it's unstable or just doesn't work properly. I haven't yet been able to navigate using it...

Comment: Yesterday, during a 2.5h drive the app sensorsstatus showed an accuracy of 5meters. But only once. I need to reproduce it. Are there logs that may tell me more about it?

Comment: I still don't have this solved. I believe this may be a hardware issue, as only a few people are affected and the software seems to be in order. I'm sending a mail to Meizu to see what they think about it. If anyone knows how to solve or troubleshoot this further than using sensorsstatus, location test, I'm very interested.

Comment: Meizu told me that it's a software issue, and a fix is included in the next update. So let's keep our eyes peeled and test this after the next update.

Comment: So, the mentioned update has run it's course, still no location by GPS satellite. Have you had any better results?

Comment: I have the same issue. My MX4 (OS version is OTA7) does not show my location when I'm using GPS. For example Google Maps says, that they can't find my location. it only works when I'm connected to wifi. Any ideas how to solve it? If not - I will fill a bug.